# sql server trigger pulling data from joined table

Tags: sql, sql-server

i want to create a trigger for insert update and delete on a table that is linked with other tables 
when any of the above happens the trigger should pull one values from the inserted table and other values from the joined tables 
and insert those into another table

here is a simplified answer, but i am getting an error on the employee join saying The multi-part identifier could not be bound

```
Create TRIGGER triggertest
ON salary 
FOR INSERT
AS 
BEGIN


DECLARE @salary int
DECLARE @firstName int


SELECT @salary = i.salary, @firstName =employee.firstName
FROM inserted i 


        INNER JOIN employee  ON
             i.employeeID = emplopyee.employeeID 
        INNER JOIN deleted d ON  i.salaryID = d.salaryID 





    INSERT INTO testTAble
    (employeeFirstName,EmployeeSalary)
    select @firstName ,@salary 

END
```

Comment: what is the datatype of  `firstname` column?

Comment: Dear, in the INSERT trigger you can't use DELETED table. Is out of scope

Comment: @DipenduPaul it looks like it ought to be a varchar but the user has it as an int

Comment: you can ignore the typo and only consider it as on-insert trigger this was just an example to explain my question which is essentially knowing if trigger could pull values from a inserted and joined tables and then insert the records into another table like in my example salary can be a inserted table where the records are inserted but can we pull data from employee table which is linked with salary table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your request can be:

**INSERT**

```
CREATE TRIGGER triggertestI
ON salary 
FOR INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO testTAble
    (employeeFirstName,EmployeeSalary)
    SELECT i.salary, employee.firstName
    FROM inserted i 
    INNER JOIN employee
    ON i.employeeID = employee.employeeID 
END
```

**UPDATE**

```
CREATE TRIGGER triggertestU
ON salary 
FOR UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    UPDATE testTAble
    SET EmployeeSalary = 
    (SELECT i.salary
    FROM inserted i 
    INNER JOIN employee
    ON i.employeeID = employee.employeeID
    where i.employeeID = testTable.employeeID)
END
```

**DELETE**

```
CREATE TRIGGER triggertestD
ON salary 
FOR DELETE
AS 
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM testTAble
    WHERE employeeID in (
    SELECT i.employeeID
    FROM deleted i 
    INNER JOIN employee
    ON i.employeeID = employee.employeeID
    where i.employeeID = testTable.employeeID)
END
```

P.S. I think, in your query the error is: emplopyee (you have add acidentally un p in the table name employee)

Answer (score 0):

error here:

```
i.employeeID = emplopyee.employeeID
```

extra `'p'` is added in your `emplopyee.employeeID`. `emplopyee` must be `employee`